# Visual feedback in a card game with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a card game and I'm stuck on how to proceed with giving a simple visual feedback when the players are interacting with the cards that are placed on board.

[image]

As you can see in the image I'd like to implement drawing arrows between the cards that interact with different object on the board (for example when the player attacks with a starship a arrow will appear between the ship and its target). When the player commits his move, the arrow needs to be drawn on the opponents gui aswell when the opponent starts his defending phase.

The whole client gui aswell as the cards are coded with swing library and are JPanels with various layouts. The cards is one class and the board gui is composed of several gui classes (handGui, heroGui, unitFieldGui etc) added together in a mainWindow gui class.

I don't really know how to proceed to achieve this kind of visual feedback and would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction, what kind of technique would help me solve this problem?

Comment: Two things will improve this question and help you gain answers: specificity and code. Please ask as specific and narrow a question possible, and please post pertinent code, preferably as a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Glass Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). a `Glass Pane` is a component that is painted over top of the frame and you can do custom painting.

You can use the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method to convert the two card components location relative to the `Glass Pane`. Then you do your custom painting to draw the arrow from one component to the other.